# Usage of quasi in "quasi turbam operum" (Columella 11.25)

Tags: word-usage, columella

In the following sentence, it is not clear to me how to interpret the usage of the word *quasi*:

*ne inter hanc quasi turbam operum neglegentius holitoris officia descripsisse videar*

The published translation by E.S. Forster and Edward Heffner has it as "...lest, amid the crowded array of tasks, I should seem to have given a somewhat careless description of the gardener’s duties". It's not clear to me how the translators are treating *quasi*. Are they treating it as if it is working in conjunction with *ne*, making sort of a joint conjunction "lest it should seem **as if** I have given...", however in that case it seems strange it is not placed with *ne*. For example, elsewhere the same author writes *ne quasi gravi perpetuae custodiae servitio contristatae senescant*, placing *quasi* with *ne*. Or are they just subsuming it into "crowded array of tasks" and not rendering it as a specific word?

That latter possibility is that we are to group *quasi* with *turbam* in the clause beginning with inter: inter hanc quasi turbam operum ("among this **throng-like** array of work"). I notice that frequently *quasi* is placed directly in front of the word it is intended to modify. For example in the sentence: *Scipio interim paulisper, ut antea dixi, in eo loco commoratus, ut quasi despexisse Caesarem videretur* where *quasi* modifies *despexisse*, not *videretur*. Another example is *Atqui plerique sic iram quasi insigne regium exercuerunt* where quasi modifies insigne regium ("as if it were a royal badge"), not the whole sentence.

So, here should I interpret *quasi* as modifying *turbam* specifically or as a conjunction affecting the whole sentence?

Answer (score 2):

It does sound good both ways, but your second option is correct. Note that the translation here is not overly literal, and "as if [it were] a crowd" works much better in Latin than in English thanks to *quasi*'s ability to go with a single word in place of a full clause (see its entry in the OLD §4b).

Syntactically, it's placement within the adjective + noun pairing is the big clue that it belongs together with them. If it went with the verb, you might see it nearer the beginning, as in your second example, or even before the verb, but it wouldn't be in between an adjective and the noun it modifies, at least not without good reason.

The other issue relates more to how Latin uses tends to use *ne* for purpose clauses and *ut non* for result clauses. Given we have *ne* here and no word that might indicate a results clause (*adeo*, *tantum*, etc.), translating it more directly for purpose (so, as my old Latin teacher would admonish, to avoid using "lest") makes it clearer that *quasi* with the verb would be odd here:

> Latin: dicam...**ne**...neglegentius holitoris officia descripsisse **videar**.
>
> English: I will speak...**so that I may not seem** to have rather carelessly described the duties of the gardener.

But *quasi* here would be redundant with *videar*. He wants to speak so that he doesn't leave an impression that he *had* done something. It might make a bit more sense were this a result clause, but even there it's unnecessary, and given it's location between the noun and adjective earlier assures that it belongs with *turbam* instead.